# Rhythmbox is invisible

Tags: 13.04, sound, rhythmbox

I tried various solutions for fixing "No Sound" problem under the Ubuntu 13.04, which got me to an odd situation in which the music or any sound plays but the Rhythmbox is neither visible at the top status bar nor anywhere on the desktop screen.

Though it is visible in the system monitor but is not accessible to bring out the GUI of the player to operate upon.
 What should I do?

---

No, sudo apt-get install --reinstall rhythmbox did not work. 
Can someone suggest any other solution, Rhythmbox is still invisible but the music is playing fine.

Comment: You can search for Rhythmbox in the OS search, this should bring up the GUI but doing this every time is annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open your terminal and do this .

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall rhythmbox
```

that will bring it back.

Comment: should I restart the PC after reinstalling it

Comment: actually no need , but if any changes have to apply means we need to. try to open it when installation done.